# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'. - Index Signature error

Tags: typescript, express, backend

I am new to TypeScript and I am getting

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

on this line -->
`const { status, msg } = codes[err.code];`

I am not too sure how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
    export const handlePSQLErrors = (
    err: { status: number; msg: string; code: string | number },
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => {
    const codes: any = {
        '22P02': { status: 400, msg: 'Bad Request' },
        42703: { status: 400, msg: 'Bad Request' },
        23502: { status: 400, msg: 'Bad Request' },
        23503: { status: 404, msg: 'Bad Request' },
    };

    function hasKey<O>(obj: O, key: keyof any): key is keyof O {
        return key in obj;
    }

    if (hasKey(err.code, codes)) {
        const { status, msg } = codes[err.code];

        res.status(status).send({ msg });
    } else next(err);
};
```

Help to explain what is going on and how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an typing issue, but there is a wrong call.

You get this error on the line:

```
const { status, msg } = codes[err.code];
```

But there real error is this:

```
if (hasKey(err.code, codes)) {
```

should be (swap the arguments)

```
if (hasKey(codes, err.code)) {
```

As `hasKey` is defined that the key is send as 2nd argument

- [Demo with this error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQimA8AcHsCcBdgGNoDsDOiAWBDVATAG1AAUBlARQBkBRWWOdYAXmAAoAoEMegLmADewTDngBXdP1RiAtgCNQsANzAZ6AOb9MsAJap1KlPlBb4u-cAA+wafMXAAvgBou3WKACO-AEqexoTBduYHdJYF90GAxQIO5UCHh+PABPDgBKFgA+QVcQFAxEIwCk1GSWHODggHIAJhqSAAYaqv4hEXEwgBYGhqdVDX4qgCEcfHC-APgqx1jK4E6agHYGgGZW4XhRCX5u3v7NYGHR8Y9-TGnnXMqalYBWJvX27fmevrUDo7HfU8mL2eu7qtHpsOjsGp03gNDiMvhNzjMrg4lBwrgAzMSoJDwHRoYC4dAAaVAyQAPAB5TJsaByABW-DJfQA1sT+MzktBUcAUmlWcTgDomGyOcAyRU5iFQOJYKhgGz+TLqTTkcEHCjgjpOWx8UTkmxFLAAHRFPpFdBpDICK7BfKYQQbLboSHqRzlU0AbX1RugxgAusirSAAPSBiXoA1PdBsCNpcOgAhsITvRxpZXcBzAUCEdCgGwJPX0FMcJFAA)
- [Demo with fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQimA8AcHsCcBdgGNoDsDOiAWBDVATAG1AAUBlARQBkBRWWOdYAXmAAoAoEMegLmADewTDngBXdP1RiAtgCNQsANzAZ6AOb9MsAJap1KlPlBb4u-cAA+wafMXAAvgBou3WKACO-AEqexoTBduYHdJYF90GAxQIO5UCHh+PABPDgBKFgA+QVcQFAxEIwCk1GSWHODggHIAJhqSAAYaqv4hEXEwgBYGhqdVDX4qgCEcfHC-APgqx1jK4E6agHYGgGZW4XhRCX5u3v7NYGHR8Y9-TGnnXMqalYBWJvX27fmevrUDo7HfU8mL2eu7qtHpsOjsGp03gNDiMvhNzjMrg4lBwrgAzMSoJDwHRoYC4dAAaVAyQAPAB5TJsaByABW-DJfQA1sT+MzktBUcAUmlWcTgDomGyOcAyRU5iFQOJYKhgGz+TLqTTkcEHCjgjpOWx8UTkmwiug+opYAA6IppDICK7BfKYQQbLYG-aOcr6gDaRtN0GMAF1kVaQAB6AMS9DGp7oNjhtJh0AENhCd6ONLK7gOYCgQjoUA2BJsI3JjhIoA)

Comment: Ahh amazing, that has done it. Been looking at it for ages, trying to work out what was going on. Thank you!